# Passport-local / Não entendo a estrutura da função

Tags: node.js, autenticação, passport-js

Estou tentando implementar o sistema de autenticação na minha plataforma utilizando Passport, Passport-local e passport-local-mongoose.

Consegui aplicar a autenticação no login:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}) ,function(req, res){
});
```

Mas não consigo entender a estrutura de autenticação ao registrar um novo usuário:

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(erro, user) {
        if(erro) {
            console.log(erro);
            return res.render("register");
        } 
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            res.redirect("/secret");
        });        

    });
});
```

Porque a estrutura que vai fazer o redirecionamento após autenticação do usuário possui essa estrutura: `passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){}`

Não consigo entender o papel desses parênteses próximos. Qual o papel deles?

Answer (score 0):

Esse segundo parênteses funciona como um `callback` da função de autenticação do passport.
O Passport vai fazer as validações e depois utilizar o que esta sendo passado no segundo parênteses para dar continuidade

Answer (score -1):

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, //aqui é requerido o username e o password 
 function(erro, user) {
    if(erro) {
        console.log(erro);
        return res.render("register"); //se tiver erro, retorna para a página register
    } 
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () { 
  //vai fazer a autenticação com os username e o password digitado pelo usuário
        res.redirect("/secret"); 
  //em caso de sucesso, é redirecionado para a página secrets
    });        

});
});
```

A documentação está aqui: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/